# Why bracket notation is working here but not the dot notation?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
var recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  }
};


console.log(recordCollection[2548])
```

This is giving error:

```
console.log(recordCollection.2548)
```

Comment: Keys cannot be numbers in an object. Wrap 2548 and 2468 in parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

MDN has a great page on [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties) that speaks directly to this (emphasis mine):

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. **However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.** This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript objects can have keys as string.
They are converted to strings with coercion.

```
var object = {
  .12e3: 'wut'
};
object[.12e3]; // 'wut'
object['.12e3']; // undefined
object['120']; // 'wut'
```

If you want to use numeric values you can use maps instead of objects.
Read more about maps here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_maps.asp